# Iterate two elements at once in a formArray in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am relatively new to angular 4 and I am stuck with the following problem:
I am building a reactive form which contains a formArray.
My form group is:

```
buildListInfoForm() {
this.listInfoForm = this._fb.group({
    id: new FormControl({value: this.currentListInfo.id, disabled: true}),
    belongsToProject: [this.currentListInfo.projectIri, Validators.required],
    labels: this._fb.array([]),
    comments: this._fb.array([])
});
```

My labels are objects:

```
labels = {     name: '',     language: '' }
```

Each label has a name and a language. I need to get the corresponding label name for each language in a reactive form.
i.e. I have a dropdown menu where I can select the language and next to it I have an input field where according to the selected language, the correct name is show. This name should be editable and also it should be possible to add more fields (language+name combinations).
I feel this should be easy to do but I am completely stuck, as I only manage to iterate either the name or the language, but not both at the same time…

```
<h4>Labels</h4>
<span *ngIf="labels" formArrayName="labels">
     <div *ngFor="let label of labels.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-form-field class="width-80">
            <input matInput
                placeholder="Value"
                formControlName="value">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="width-10">
            <mat-select formControlName="language">
                <mat-option value="" disabled>Select language</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="en">en</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="de">de</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="fr">fr</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="it">it</mat-option>
                <!--<mat-option *ngFor="let label of labels.controls" [value]="label.get('language').value">-->
                <!--{{label.get('language').value}}-->
                <!--</mat-option>-->
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
     </div>
     <button mat-button
        class="right"
        [color]="'primary'"
        (click)="addLabel()">
            Add Label
     </button>
</span>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `select` element for each label in a loop. I guess that's not what you need. If you absolutely need to have an input next to each option you can wrap the options into divs and add an input tag next to each option like so:

```
<h4>Labels</h4>
<span *ngIf="labels" formArrayName="labels">
    <mat-select formControlName="language">
        <div *ngFor="let label of labels.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field class="width-80">
                <input matInput
                    placeholder="Value"
                    value="label.get('name').value"
                    formControlName="value">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="width-10">
                <mat-option value="" disabled>Select language</mat-option>
                <mat-option[value]="label.get('language').value">
                    {{label.get('language').value}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </mat-select>
    <button mat-button
        class="right"
        [color]="'primary'"
        (click)="addLabel()">
            Add Label
    </button>
</span>
```

Comment: What I want is to have a `select` element on the left with the different languages as the `options` (taken from the array) and on the right side an `input` field that displays the name corresponding to the language. So basically one line with one `select` and one `input` element iterating all the array items, and not many lines with one array item each.

Comment: In the code you suggested I get three selection fields and the three corresponding input fields...