# Angular: FormArray is not iterating

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular9

> Firstly sorry for creating a long post but I had no option other than
>   this as I need to explain where am facing issue.

I have a form where a control is an array of JSON. I've created a reactive form wrt that. Below is my JSON and my TS code:

**JSON (got from backend request)**

```
{
    "questionList": [
        {
            "questionCategory": {
                "questionCategoryName": "JAVA",
                "id": 40,
                "isActive": true,
                "timestamp": "2020-06-12 14:06:47.325"
            },
            "difficultyLevel": 0,
            "options": [
                {
                    "answer": false,
                    "id": 2,
                    "optionText": "method",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-18 17:17:11.75"
                },
                {
                    "answer": false,
                    "id": 3,
                    "optionText": "name",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-18 17:17:11.753"
                },
                {
                    "answer": false,
                    "id": 4,
                    "optionText": "class",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-18 17:17:11.758"
                },
                {
                    "answer": true,
                    "id": 1,
                    "optionText": "variable",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-18 17:17:11.663"
                }
            ],
            "section": {
                "marksPerQuestion": 3,
                "id": 8,
                "isActive": true
            },
            "id": 1,
            "isActive": true,
            "questionText": "What is a variable ?",
            "timestamp": "2020-06-18 17:17:10.946"
        },
        {
            "questionCategory": {
                "questionCategoryName": "APTITUDE",
                "id": 41,
                "isActive": true
            },
            "difficultyLevel": 0,
            "options": [
                {
                    "answer": true,
                    "id": 6,
                    "optionText": "xyz",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-17 21:50:48.975"
                },
                {
                    "answer": true,
                    "id": 5,
                    "optionText": "abc",
                    "timestamp": "2020-06-17 21:50:48.907"
                }
            ],
            "section": {
                "marksPerQuestion": 2,
                "id": 7,
                "isActive": true,
                "timestamp": "2020-06-12 14:08:14.181"
            },
            "id": 2,
            "isActive": true,
            "questionText": "What is def",
            "timestamp": "2020-06-17 21:50:48.6"
        }
    ],
    "empty": false
}
```

**TS Code for this JSON**

```
updateQuestionForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [], isActive: [], difficultyLevel: [0], questionText: [''],
  questionCategory: this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    questionCategoryName: ['']
  }),
  section: this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    marksPerQuestion: ['']
  }),
  options: new FormArray([])
});

optionForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [], optionText: [''], answer: []
});

onEdit(e) {
  const formArray: FormArray = this.updateQuestionForm.get('options') as FormArray;
  this.updateQuestionForm.controls['id'].setValue(e.id);
  this.updateQuestionForm.controls['isActive'].setValue(e.isActive);
  this.updateQuestionForm.controls['questionText'].setValue(e.questionText);
  this.updateQuestionForm.controls['questionCategory'].setValue({
    id: e.questionCategory.id,
    questionCategoryName: e.questionCategory.questionCategoryName
  });
  this.updateQuestionForm.controls['section'].setValue({
    id: e.section.id,
    marksPerQuestion: e.section.marksPerQuestion
  });
  for(let i of e.options) {
    this.optionForm.controls['id'].setValue(i.id);
    this.optionForm.controls['optionText'].setValue(i.optionText);
    this.optionForm.controls['answer'].setValue(i.answer);
    formArray.push(new FormControl(this.optionForm.value));
  }
  console.log(this.updateQuestionForm.value);
}

get Status() {
  return this.updateQuestionForm.get('isActive');
}

get Options(): FormArray {
  return this.updateQuestionForm.get('options') as FormArray;
}
```

Let me explain what the TS states:
Firstly, I am creating a form of `updateQuestionForm` which is the main form for the JSON.
The second form of `optionForm` is for the `options` FormArray of `updateQuestionForm`.
I've created this second form because I need certain controls from the array. So this stuck in my mind.
The `onEdit()` method is triggered by a button click which fetches the JSON from a `Mat-Table`.

**The HTML form**

```
<form [formGroup]="updateQuestionForm" (submit)="onUpdateQuestionForm()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Enter Question</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="questionText">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <mat-form-field formGroupName="questionCategory">
        <mat-label>Question Category</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="id">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let q of QuestionCategory;">
            <mat-option [value]="q.id">{{ q.questionCategoryName }}</mat-option>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <mat-form-field formGroupName="section">
        <mat-label>Marks</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="id">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let m of Marks;">
            <mat-option [value]="m.id">{{ m.marksPerQuestion }}</mat-option>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <mat-label>Status</mat-label><br>
      <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="isActive">{{ Status ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Options & Answers</h3>
  <div formArrayName="options">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let o of Options.value; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Option</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="optionText">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <mat-label>Answer</mat-label><br>
        <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="answer">
           {{ answer ? 'True' : 'False' }}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button mat-flat-button type="submit" style="background-color: #28a745; color: white;">Update</button>
</form>
```

This is the form of the JSON. I'm successfully able to fetch and store the value for the controls `questionCategory`, `section`, `isActive`, `questionText`. The problem is occurring for the `options` control. There I have 4 options (with 4 `optionText`, 4 `answer` each fetched from the database; **refer the sample JSON above**).
But I am not able to display the controls. Looks like the `ngFor` inside `formArrayName="options"` is not working. After the `h2`, nothing is coming.

Please help me. FYI I was following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682815/iterate-two-elements-at-once-in-a-formarray-in-angular-4) for the formArrayName looping part.

[image: Here's the initial view]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, With the `updateQuestionForm ` you are trying to create the JSON structure you have mentioned above? 
Or are you trying to take answers from the user for the given questions list?

Comment: @Harish yes. Actually this is an update form, the ```onEdit()``` method is fetching values and initializing it in the ```updateQuestionForm``` controls. These values will be retrieved in the view part with the controls. And then if the value gets changed the ```Update``` button will send the values to the backend which I'll integrate later for timing I need the options to get rendered to view.

Comment: So basically, you are using this form to update the questions and the options, right?
If yes, the structure of your form is complex and can be simplified. Firstly you don't need the `optionForm`.

Comment: yes, I am using this as an update form. Then please suggest me the simplified approach

Comment: Don't mind these multiple questions I am asking. Are you using this form to update a single question or multiple questions at once?
I am trying to write the code on stackbliz for you to easily understand the fix.

Comment: actually I was using the ```optionForm``` to get rid of the ```timestamp```. Firstly I was doing a simple approach: ```this.optionForm.controls['options'].setValue(e.options);``` where in the ```updateQuestionForm``` I was keeping ````options: [ ]``` like this

Comment: @Harish I want to update single question. I'm updating my question with the view I currently have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216216/discussion-between-harish-and-avishek-datta-ray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you don't need two forms to update the question data and your code looks complex.

I have simplified your code and it is working fine for me. You can check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-forms-array).

**What did I do?**

1) Basically, I have created a simple form structure in `ngOnInit()` based on your code samples.

2) I have written `updateQuestionData()` function where I am patching the form with the JSON data. I have iterated over the `options` and created a form group for each `option`.

You can modify the values on the form and see the how `updateQuestionForm` is updating.

I hope this simplifies your use case and optimizes your code.

Comment: thanks, brother. It's working fine. You have made the code so simple :)